# ¿Cómo puedo desinstalar pip de rocky linux?

Tags: python, linux

Lo que pasa es que instale pip con una version de python 3.9, pero el programa que estoy usando me pide tener una version de pip con python 3.7, entonces cuando quise desinstalar pip no encuentro forma alguna de hacerlo, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: una opción para no desinstalar sería que utilizaras un entorno virtual para el programa que necesitas con `python3.7 -m venv py37`

Answer (score 0):

## Si no instalaste pip con `dnf`

`pip uninstall pip`
o bien
`python3.9 -m pip uninstall pip`

## Si lo instalaste con `dnf`

`sudo dnf remove python39-pip`